# Booleans, arrays, and not typing 256 possible scenarios

Tags: arrays, boolean, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a program based around 8 boolean statements.
I build the `array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];`.
For each possible combination I need to make the program output a different text. 
To make things simpler, I can remove any possibilities that contain less than 3 true statements.
For example: `if (array === [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]){console.log('Targets: 4, 5, 6, 7')};` 
Is it possible to have it set so that if the value is false it's added to then end of "Targets: "? I'm very new to coding as a hobby and have only made 1 extensive program. I feel like `{console.log("Targets: " + if(array[0]===0){console.log(" 1,")} + if(array[2]===0)...}`would portay what I'm looking for but it's terrible as a code.

I'm sure that someone has had this issue before but I don't think I'm experienced enough to be searching with the correct keywords.

PS: I'd greatly appreciate it if we can stick to the very basics as I haven't had any luck with installing new elements other than discord.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you need:

```js
const values = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0];
const positions = values.map((v, i) => !v ? i : null).filter(v => v != null);

console.log('Target: ' + positions.join(', '));
```

In essence:

1. [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each value to its respective index if the value is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (0 is considered falsy), otherwise map it to [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null).
2. [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out all `null` values.
3. [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) all remaining indexes to a string.

---

To address your additional requirements:

```js
const locations = ['Trees', 'Rocks', 'L1', 'R1', 'L2', 'R2', 'L3', 'R3'];
const values = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0];
const result = values.map((v, i) => !v ? locations[i] : null).filter(v => v != null);

console.log('Target: ' + result.join(', '));
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for helping out! I think this will be slightly more complicated than I had anticipated.

Comment: For simplicity, let's reorganize the code and develop a backbone.  
`const dead = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]   
const alive = dead.map((v, i) => !v ? i : null).filter(v => v != null);  
  
console.log('Target: ' + alive.join(', '));`  
This would print out "Target: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" or am I missunderstanding [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?
Ideal Output: "Target: R1, L2, R2, L3, R3"   
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you tried to just click **Run code snippet** below my answer? If you had, you would see that the output is `Target: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`.  Also, there is nothing in your question about whatever logic is required to get to an output of `Target: R1, L2, R2, L3, R3`.

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow and looked over the button like it was add. Appologies for not providing enough information, I try to simplify my requirements so that they are more useful to other individuals. In short, I'm making a Discord.Js bot for the Pleasure Gardens encounter in Destiny 2's Leviathan Raid. In this encounter there are 8 different locations that each have a target. The locations are named as follows in order of the appropriate index: Trees, Rocks, L1, R1, L2, R2, L3, and R3. I need the program to detect wether the target is dead and alert teammates if a location needs help.